# Making multiple points on single location all visible at once

Tags: qgis, point, symbology, vector

I am having an issue with visibility of multiple symbols at the same location. The scenario is: I am an archaeologist, dealing with groups of objects all buried together at the same time ("hoards"), which of course all have the same spatial location. Hoards can be composed of objects of different materials, e.g. gold, bronze, amber objects etc.

I am trying to make a map of distribution of different materials, and I have used categorized symbols to indicate different materials, but only the uppermost symbol is visible. I thought of possibly making the symbols different sizes so that a bit of each symbol would peek out, but that implies quantitative significance. I thought maybe there might be a way to slightly offset each symbol, or maybe to make a tiny pie chart? Any help?

[image: A screen shot of the map as it is now, with the categorized symbols under 'MBA_orns' layer.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the options you mentioned have their pros and cons. If using the stacked symbology approach, you may consider setting the [symbol levels](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#symbol-levels) and making the symbols progressively larger towards the bottom of the stack. With careful symbol selection it is possible to avoid implying quantitative significance. Alternately, you may consider applying an [offset to each of the symbols](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/style_library.html#marker-symbols) in the xy direction. This method can possibly convey an incorrect spatial location to your points though.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend "Point displacement" renderer. You can combine it with your existing categorized renderer. I invite you to play a little with the settings to get your personal optimized result:

[image]

Alternatively you could also try "Point cluster" renderer.